# Аналог IP Россия

Tags: dns, ipv4

Во всем мире, изначально, IP адреса ipv4 выдает американская icaan. А есть ли в России, в связи с санкциями со стороны запада и риском отключения нас от получения ipv4, какой то аналог, чтобы продолжило все работает при таком сценарии? Чтобы внутри страны интернет не пропал и мы могли выходить в сеть? Связано ли с этим как то российский корневой DNS НСДИ и как вообще это работает в случае если icaan лишит нас своих IP?

Comment: Нету, но в случае занавеса думаю, что-то состряпают. Не только американская - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: думаю на базе - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A1